# How to make NSWindow accept mouseMove events immediately after opening?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I am writing an application using cocoa which, in some point (surprise), opens window.
There is a "Hover" functionality in this window, and for that I need to accept mouseMoved events. I managed to activate this functionality using

```
[[newView window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
```

call, however, it only starting to work after I touch the opened window, actually activating it this way. I am interested for it to work right away, without clicking on it.

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

does not seem to be working since only mouseDown or mouseDragged events activate it. Apparently mouseMoved event does not.

In other words, mouseMoved event only start to work after mouseDown or mouseDragged event has been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an [NSTrackingArea](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html) to handle this? Have you passed in the NSTrackingActiveAlways option?

Comment: Actually, no. And this was exactly what I had to do. Thank you! :)